# Terraform Forwarding Rule Quota Exceeded

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

In terraform I am trying to create a forwarding rule and I am getting the following error.  It says that my limit is 250 however when I go into the project (under iam/quotas) and I look for the quota limit for "Internal TCP/UDP Load Balancer Forwarding Rules per VPC Network" I see that it is under 250.

Am I looking at the wrong quota in the gcp console?
Is the current usage on the gcp console showing a delayed value?
How does terraform get the current quota value?

```
Error waiting to create ForwardingRule: Error waiting for Creating ForwardingRule: You cannot create any more internal forwarding rules in the project, as the limit of '250.0' for network peering group is reached for the network 'GLOBAL:global/COMPUTE/PROJECT:SAMPLE_PROJECT/NETWORK:vpc-network'.
```

Comment: The quota limit take some time to update. So maybe you should wait a little bit before rechecking the quota

Comment: How can I get the most updated value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error message you are getting,  I saw that you're using VPC peering.

You need take in consideration that if you use VPC peering, the limit for [INTERNAL_FORWARDING_RULES_PER_NETWORK](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/quota#per_network) change, the forwarding rules will be added for each peering in your VPC with the quota for the other VPC(s). You can see more specific details in [VPC Network Peering limits](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/quota#vpc-peering).

This document discusses [Effective limits for VPC Network Peering](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/quota#vpc-peering-effective-limit)

To increase the quota you can follow these [steps](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#requesting_additional_quota) or open a case directly with [GCP Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/manage-cases#creating_cases) and ask for your quota increase.

Comment: If possible, add this link to your answer. This document discusses **Effective limits for VPC Network Peering** https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/quota#vpc-peering-effective-limit

Comment: On that doc, can anyone explain the different between "peer network" and "peering group"?